# Using increment like operator in a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop downlist named `MonthDropDownList` consisting of months bounded by a sql data source.
Now i want to access the value of `MonthDropDownList` like

```
MonthDropDownList.selecteditem++.
```

So

```
if MonthDropDownList.selecteditem=January 
    then MonthDropDownList.selecteditem++=Febraury
```

How can i achieve this???

This is my code

```
DataClassesDataContext db = null;
    db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    tblAdvance advance = new tblAdvance();
    advance.StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(StudentNameDropDownList.SelectedValue);
    advance.FromMonth = FromMonthDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
    advance.UptoMonth = ToMonthDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
    advance.AdvanceAmount = Convert.ToInt32(txtAdvanceAmount.Text);
    advance.RollNo = Convert.ToInt32(txtRollNo.Text);
    db.tblAdvances.InsertOnSubmit(advance);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    db.Connection.Close();
    db.Dispose();
    for (int i = FromMonthDropDownList.SelectedIndex; i <= ToMonthDropDownList.SelectedIndex;i++ )
    {
     DataClassesDataContext dc = null;
     dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
     tblTotalFee bill = new tblTotalFee();
     bill.StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(StudentNameDropDownList.SelectedValue);
```

> bill.MonthName=FromMonthDropDownList.SelectedIndex[i]

```
        bill.DueFromPreviousMonth = 0;
        bill.ECAFee = 0;
        bill.HostelFee = 0;
        bill.LateFeeCharges = 0;
        bill.MonthlyFee = 0;
        bill.TransportFee = 0;
        bill.TotalFeeThisMonthAlongwithDueinthismonth=0;
        dc.tblTotalFees.InsertOnSubmit(bill);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
I want something like the blockquoted line
        dc.Connection.Close();
        dc.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

create an array of months
use it's index to get added month

```
string[] months = new string[] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
         "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

Suppose you have a `dropdownlist` with id `dd1` and in values you have `0,1,2,......`

The if you need to find `February` and you have value `1` then you can do like this

```
int current month=1;
string nextmonth=months[current+1];
```

Comment: In simple words,i have upper month and lower month as two drop down lists. Then I have a loop inside which if i place upper month as january and lower month as march then uppermonth++ should be febraury and again uppermonth++ must imply march.....This is my actual requirement @Shekhar

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you have two dropdown lists functioning as an upper and lower bound for months, then your SelectedValue++ function would look like this (VB.NET):

```
Public Function GetNextMonth(ByVal dd1 as DropDownList, Byval dd2 as DropDownList) as String
     If dd1.Items(dd1.SelectedIndex + 1).SelectedValue >= dd2.SelectedValue then
            Return dd2.SelectedItem.Text
     else
            Return dd1.Items(dd1.SelectedIndex + 1).Text
     end if
End Sub
```

This would return the next month in your list unless the month in your "lower bound" list is equal to or greater than the one in your "upper bound" list, in which case it would simply return the upper bound month.

Is this what you mean, or did you need something that's recursive?

Comment: In simple words,i have upper month and lower month as two drop down lists. Then I have a loop inside which if i place upper month as january and lower month as march then uppermonth++ should be febraury and again uppermonth++ must imply march

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys with this code. It was simple but may be i felt the problem was too complex....

```
 DataClassesDataContext db = null;
    db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    tblAdvance advance = new tblAdvance();
    advance.StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(StudentNameDropDownList.SelectedValue);
    advance.FromMonth = FromMonthDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
    advance.UptoMonth = ToMonthDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
    advance.AdvanceAmount = Convert.ToInt32(txtAdvanceAmount.Text);
    advance.RollNo = Convert.ToInt32(txtRollNo.Text);
    db.tblAdvances.InsertOnSubmit(advance);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    db.Connection.Close();
    db.Dispose();
    int k = FromMonthDropDownList.SelectedIndex;
    int l = ToMonthDropDownList.SelectedIndex;
    for (int i = k; i <= l;i++ )
    {
        DataClassesDataContext dc = null;
        dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
        tblTotalFee bill = new tblTotalFee();
        bill.StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(StudentNameDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        bill.MonthName = FromMonthDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
        bill.DueFromPreviousMonth = 0;
        bill.ECAFee = 0;
        bill.HostelFee = 0;
        bill.LateFeeCharges = 0;
        bill.MonthlyFee = 0;
        bill.TransportFee = 0;
        bill.TotalFeeThisMonthAlongwithDueinthismonth=0;
        FromMonthDropDownList.SelectedIndex++;
        dc.tblTotalFees.InsertOnSubmit(bill);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
        dc.Connection.Close();
        dc.Dispose();
        }
}
```